# Load external libraries in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a firefox addon with the addon sdk, but I don't succeed in importing external libraries in the addon. Important to know is that the addon opens a new tab in which I need the imported libraries.

This is my folder structure:

```
> data
   > jquery.js
   > pixlr.js
> lib
   > main.js
```

To import the libraries jquery.js and pixlr.js, I have tried already multiple things. As these libraries need to be accessible in the new tab, I have tried the following:

```
tabs.open({
    url: startURL,
    inNewWindow: inNewWindow,
    inBackground: inBackground,
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.js")],
    onReady: function (tab) {
        tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.js"),
                                self.data.url("pixlr.js")]
        });
    }
});
```

Does anybody know why this would not work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more information, please? When does your extension call the `tabs.open`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer from erikvold did work for me, I also found another (and a bit simpler) solution:

```
Cu.import(self.data.url("pixlr.js", this));
Cu.import(self.data.url("urlShortener.js", this));
```

You can just use the import functionality provided by Firefox addon sdk instead. I also wanted to have jquery included, but this didn't work very well for the sandbox mode in which the addon runs. Since I mainly used jquery to send an ajax request, I instead used the Request module also provided by the Firefox addon sdk.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know why this would help you at all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `startURL` is a url for a file in your add-on, (although you have not made clear what the `startURL` is for).

Try this:

```
tabs.open({
    url: startURL,
    inNewWindow: inNewWindow,
    inBackground: inBackground,
    onReady: function (tab) {
        tab.attach({
          contentScript: "self.options.urls.forEach(url => {" +
                           "var script = document.createElement('script')" +
                           "script.src = url;" +
                           "document.body.appendChild(script);" +
                         "});",
          contentScriptOptions: {
            urls: [
                self.data.url("jquery.js"),
                self.data.url("pixlr.js")
            ]
          }
        });
    }
});
```